# AWS Cognito -> SSO reconciliation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I need to ensure my app knows my user even if he signs in using a variety of supported methods (OTP, email/password, Google, etc.).

How do I make it so?

Comment: What have your tried?  The [Cognito Userinfo endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/userinfo-endpoint.html) returns much of this information but it's unclear if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to ensure my app knows my user even if he signs in using a variety of supported methods (OTP, email/password, Google, etc.).

Deciding if it's the same "he" who signs in is the hard part. This is a product security decision, not a technical one.

These are some common patterns:

- Trust the email claim in Google's and Facebook's tokens
- Have the users explicitly link their accounts with an additional confirmation step (log in via Google, log in via Facebook; click "merge accounts")
- Require the email or phone number confirmation for every account and merge the accounts if emails or phone numbers match

and so on.

There are threat models relevant to every one of these options, and it's up to you to decide how to deal with them.

> How do I make it so?

If you workflow is simple (just checking the existing attributes like email or phone number, with no user interaction), you can set up a [pre sign-up lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-sign-up.html) which will create a new user or link to an existing one once Cognito sees a new identity from a federated provider.

If you logic is more complex, then, once you have decided that, for your purposes, a Google ID and a Facebook ID belong to the same person, you link them to the same user profile in Cognito by calling [`AdminLinkProviderForUser`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminLinkProviderForUser.html).